# MVC4 how to display error message when a condition is / isn't met?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, conditional-statements

How do I display error messages in MVC4 when a condition is or isn't met?

I have this block of code in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteOwner(int OwnerID)
{
    Owner dbEntry = _DBContext.Owners.Find(OwnerID);

    if (dbEntry != null)
    {
        if (dbEntry.GroupTypes.Count == 0)
        {
            _DBContext.Owners.Remove(dbEntry);
            _DBContext.SaveChanges();  
        }
        else
        {
            //Throw a validation message                
        }  
    }

   return RedirectToAction("GetListOfOwners");
}
```

The above block of code stops a user form deleting any owner from the database who has at least one or greater associated GroupTypes.

It works but at present it's just returning the user back to the page, what I'd like to know is how would I display an appropriate error message which tells the user why the owner hasn't been removed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you considered putting an error message into the `ViewBag`?

Comment: Yes, but wanted to try and avoid using a viewbag if possbile

Comment: pass a string to 'GetListOfOwners' as you are going back to this action. then set viewbag.Error = string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to add errors, then display them on the view:

```
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your message here");
    return View("NameOfView");
}
```

On the view, add `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to display the errors.

Comment: I forgot about `ModelState`.  I'm glad to have the refresher. Here's your +1.

Comment: Thanks @CodeswithHammer